# Magento addBeforeInitFunction in the payment class

Tags: javascript, magento, checkout, credit-card

In the magento script `optcheckout.js -> Payment(Class)` there is a function

```
 addBeforeInitFunction
```

The payment function is instantiated on the payment.phtml page.

```
var payment = new Payment('co-payment-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/savePayment') ?>');

console.log(payment.form);

payment.addBeforeInitFunction('test', function(){
    console.log('test');
});
payment.addAfterInitFunction('test1', function(){
    console.log('test1');
});
payment.addBeforeValidateFunction('test2', function(){
    console.log('test2');
});
payment.addAfterValidateFunction('test3'), function() {
    console.log('test3');
}
```

Should I be adding these calls somewhere else?  The only one that registers to the Hash is `addAfterValidateFunction`.  Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: maybe will be helpfull http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158644/9951

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but after this last version 1.9.1, I cant load/run script tags inside child blocks.
Until 1.7 I could set a child for Credit Card Form Block using events, and apply some javascripts inside. Now it won't works. So that payment methods seems very useful.